# XML RESPONSE:[object Text] is getting from the xml response?how to convert [object Text]?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have `js` page. I need to get values from xml as,

> 37.220941081285 -76.650414191206 37.222866 -76.689166 37.221250370692 -76.69331520088 37.222969 -76.693565 37.226402 -76.694478 37.225778 -76.693886 37.223506 -76.693278 37.223218 -76.69235 37.22261 -76.678494 37.222866 -76.663581 37.221186 -76.650973 37.220941081285 -76.650414191206

but now i get values as,

> [object Text]

How can I convert my `[object Text]` values to `37.220941081285 -76.650414191206 37.222866 -76.689166 37.221250370692 -76.69331520088 37.222969 -76.693565 37.226402 -76.694478 37.225778 -76.693886 37.223506 -76.693278 37.223218 -76.69235 37.22261 -76.678494 37.222866 -76.663581 37.221186 -76.650973 37.220941081285 -76.650414191206`?

Comment: Code, code, wherefore art thou, code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting back a `Text` element. You can access the textual content of that element using [`.nodeValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68D080).

E.g., assuming `data` is whatever variable you were outputting that gave you `[object Text]`, you'd use:

```
var theText = data.nodeValue;
```

...to get the text within it.

Comment: in my [object text] i have four values,how i get that four values.

Comment: @AravinthaBashyam.c: Based on what little information you've provided, I'd think `String#split` on a space and then `parseFloat` on the elements of the resulting array.